# Timestamp column - Can it be queried?

Tags: sql-server

Can a Timestamp (rowversion) column in a SQL Server table be queried? If so, how?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
Select * From MyTable Where MyTimestampColumn = "???"
```

But am not sure what to put in for "???"

Thanks - Randy

Comment: Could you explain what problem you are trying to solve rather than how you are trying to solve it? What sort of query are you trying to write? What should it do? What is your data? What output do you expect?

Comment: @Mark Byers - It's a bit complicated but suffice it to say I simply want to search a Timestamp column for a specific value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `timestamp` datatype is equivalent to `binary(8)`. You can query against it:

```
create table #t (somecolumn varchar(64), mytimestampcolumn timestamp)

insert into #t (somecolumn) select 'hello world'
insert into #t (somecolumn) select 'foo'
select * from #t where mytimestampcolumn = 0x0000000000000978 -- this value will vary 

drop table #t
```

Note that timestamp has been deprecated in Sql Server 2008. In previous versions of SQL Server (2005, 2000), `rowversion` is a synonym for `timestamp` to help with future migration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's effectively `binary(8)`.

Why use it otherwise? It's only use is to detect other changes to a row on UPDATE. Otherwise, you have to test all columns in the row for changes. MS Access especially relies on it for concurrency

Answer (score 0):

A SQL Server timestamp column is for row versioning, and doesn't relate to time (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx)

However, it is often queried (either explicitly or implicitly) in concurrency checking code for multi user applications.